# How to submit jquery jwysiwyg on enter

Tags: rte, jwysiwyg

I am using jquery rich text editor [jwysiwyg](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg)  , i am able to submit the content on pressing enter key, by adding line

```
if(event.keyCode == 13) {
     jQuery('#submit_button_id').focus().click();
                                      
}
```

in function `$(this.editorDoc).keyup(function (event)`

Problem now is shift+ENTER key also submit the value , cursor is not going to new line.
Is there any way such that on pressing shift+ENTER goes to new line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to store whether shift is down in a variable. So in keydown you'll have (in pseudocode):

```
if(event.keyCode === KEYCODE_SHIFT) shiftDown = true;
```

and in keyup the opposite

```
if(event.keyCode === KEYCODE_SHIFT) shiftDown = false;
```

and then in keyup check:

```
if(event.keyCode === 13 && !shiftDown) { 
    ...
```

**EDIT**
Actually, you can probably just use the `event.shiftKey` property:

```
if(!event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 13) {
    ...
```